# How to update document in NoSQL database like mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We are using **mongo dB** in our application with **C# as language.**

Currently we are loading entire document as object in C#.

**Make changes to document which happens in memory, and look like very costly.**

and then call **ReplaceOrSave** method on mongo collection.

**Is there a way in mongoDB, where can just update few fields directly in mongoDB server,** without loading entire document in memory. Like we do in SQL database with update statement.

Comment: Take a look here:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/getting_started/quick_tour/#updating-documents

Comment: If you mean that entity statement like EF(ORM), there isn't it in MongoDb C# driver.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response.